# Photo Competition 2022-01-03: Environmental Destruction

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Environmental Destruction

Deforestation, plastic pollution, chemical spills, quarrying, deliberate burning.

This theme was suggested by [niemiro](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/44811/niemiro).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128177/photo-competition-2022-01-03-environmental-destruction?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on January 17, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Road to destruction]

## Road to destruction

PANASONIC LUMIX GX80

f:8
Ss:1/320th
42mm
Iso:200
Demolition a bridge over the A50 near Uttoxeter, UK. Replacement Bridge and new roads to follow....

Answer (score 4):

## Plastic Life

09/09/2017, Shanghai

EOS 6D, EF50 f/1.8 II, f/2, 1/400, ISO100

[image: Plastic Life]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Clear-cut]

**Clear-cut**

```
Fujifilm X-E3, 1/60s, ISO 320

Location: Halver, NRW, Germany
Date: 12.09.2020, 19:31:51(WET)
```

Many forests have been chopped down in this area over the last couple years. The bark beetle population rose and by now most of the cultivated pine trees are dead.

Answer (score 2):

**Sunset Smokestack**

[image: Smokestack at Sunset from Brooklyn Bridge]

A smokestack spewing something into the air at sunset on January 31, 2015.  Taken from the center of the Brooklyn Bridge.

Canon EOS 6D, 100-300mm @205mm, f/8.0, 1/500 second, ISO 100